# Automatically trigger translation notification through workflow

Tags: 2011, workflow

We are running SDL Tridion 2011 SP1. We have the below workflow definition:

1. Create/Edit (Manual)
2. Review (Manual)
3. Approve (Manual)
4. Publish (Automatic)
5. Trigger Translation Notification

Is it possible to initiate the workflow for the corresponding component in the child publication (for localizing) so that the translator would see the item in their "Assignment List"? Otherwise there is no way (apart from the Translation Email Notification) for the translator to know if there is some new tasks for them.

Comment: Could you please tag this question with the appropriate Tridion version? The answer will be different for Tridion 2013 compared to earlier versions!

Answer (score 2):

In **Tridion 2013** there is an explicit way to start workflow on any number of items. However prior to that it was not possible to start a workflow process. I would recommend creating an `EventHandler` and subscribing to `LocalizeEventArgs` asynchronously. In the event handler you could wait a while for the item to be localized and then `CheckOut` and `Save` the item to start the associated editing workflow. This `Save` operation will be a dummy save to initiate the editing workflow, no change of the item should be done. The event handler should be asynchronous to allow the localize action to be finished. However, keep in mind that in that publication the item should have a workflow `Process Definition` defined.

Comment: So you're suggesting to have an Automatic Activity after the approval of the component in Primary language that localizes the component in the child publication and triggers the workflow?

Comment: Keep in mind that localizing in an automatic activity will result in the last checked-in version being localized, not the one that is in workflow. If you want to automate the process you can `Localize` and do the `Checkout` and `Save` in `EventDeliveryPhase.Processed` of `FinishProcessEventArgs`.